# Adding a field from an object in an array to another field of an object within the same array MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

I quite need help with updating a document in MongoDB.

So here's my problem. I need to remove the object inside the records array that has the type OLD however before removing it, I'll be needing to add it's value to the object that has type CURRENT. So given the example below. The query should change the value of CURRENT object to 120 and the object that has type OLD will be removed;

I can't make it two queries since this query will be updating thousands of data.

This is in node.js using mongoose.

Thank you in advanced!

```
{
    name: 'Test',
    records: [
        {
            type: 'NEW',
            value: 50,
        },
        {
            type: 'OLD',
            value: 100,
        },
        {
            type: 'CURRENT',
            value: 20
        } 
    ]
}
```

Comment: Well it's kinda however that's not actually hte problem. It would be easy for me to pull or delete the object out from the array. The thing is I need to add it to antoher object within the array before I remove it

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) from MongoDB v4.2,

- first match type with `CURRENT`
- first `$set` to sum the value of type `CURRENT` and type `OLD`
- second `$set` to remove type `OLD`

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  { "records.type": "CURRENT" },
  [{
    $set: {
      records: {
        $map: {
          input: "$records",
          as: "r",
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: { $eq: ["$$r.type", "CURRENT"] },
              then: {
                type: "$$r.type",
                value: {
                  $add: [
                    "$$r.value",
                    {
                      $reduce: {
                        input: "$records",
                        initialValue: 0,
                        in: {
                          $cond: {
                            if: { $eq: ["$$this.type", "OLD" ] },
                            then: { $add: ["$$this.value", "$$value"] },
                            else: "$$value"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              else: "$$r"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      records: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$records",
          as: "r",
          cond: { $ne: ["$$r.type", "OLD"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```